# Proof of capacitive reactance equation

Tags: capacitor, reactance

I have a doubt about the ratio of potential difference and current of capacitor $$X_c = \frac{v}{i} = \frac{1}{\omega C}$$

If I have a sinusoidal potential difference $$v = V_Msin(\omega t)$$ and the capacity relation $$i = C\frac{dv(t)}{dt} $$ so $$i = \omega CV_Mcos(\omega t) $$ finally \$X_c\$ should be $$X_c = \frac{V_M sin(\omega t)}{\omega CV_M cos(\omega t)} \neq \frac{1}{\omega C} $$
What's wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with expressing oscillating quantities as complex numbers? The capacitor's impedance is an *imaginary* number.

Comment: So why the tan value is not considered?

Comment: While sin(x)/cos(x) equals to tan(x), it does not make much sense here. What you might be interested noticing that sin(x) and cos(x) have a 90 degree phase difference which might help you forward.

Comment: If it's a complex number, the phase and magnitude information are combined. Only when you take the magnitude or phase of a complex number can they be considered separately.

Comment: @Simone, the problem is that you are missing the ***definition*** of reactance for how it is to be applied. As it is supposed to be applied, you are to take it as \$\frac{\pi}2\$ out of phase. (For inductance, oppositely out of phase.) It's ***not*** in-phase with resistance. You've not included the additional phase term that would be required when ***interpreting*** your final result. Include it, and you have your solution.

Comment: @Simone Remember that for the purposes of the *reactance concept*, current ***leads*** voltage by \$\frac{\pi}2\$ in a capacitor and ***lags*** by \$\frac{\pi}2\$ in an inductor. The concept of *reactance*, by definition, must be considered as orthogonal to resistance. Reactance is a simplification so that non-calculus folks and do common AC analysis. (It's lots easier to just apply Laplace and solve for impedance, though, without having to worry about)

Comment: @Simone Final note. In Laplace, \$s\$ is an operator where \$s=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\, t}\fbox{}\$ and \$\frac1s=\int\fbox{}\:\text{d}t\$. Start with: \$I_{_\text{C}}=C\:\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\, t}V_{_\text{C}}\$. Substitute in the Laplace operator to get \$I_{_\text{C}}=C\:s\: V_C\$. Reworked: \$Z_C=\frac{V_C}{I_C}=\frac1{s\,C}\$. Using operators makes it easy. Apply it now to \$V_{_\text{L}}=L\:\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\, t}\, I_{_\text{L}}= L\:s\: I_L\$. So \$Z_L=\frac{V_L}{I_L}=s\, L\$! Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's wrong?

Your final approach.

---

First, here's a simpler proof:

$$
\mathrm{
dq = C \ dv_C(t) = i(t)\ dt
\\
\Rightarrow i(t) = C \ \frac{dv_C(t)}{dt}
\\
\frac{d}{dt}=j\omega \ \Rightarrow i(t) = v_C(t) (j\omega \ C)
\\
\Rightarrow  Z_C=\frac{v_C(t)}{i(t)}=\frac{1}{j\omega \ C}
\\
X_C=|Z_C|=\frac{1}{\omega \ C}
}
$$

---

Now, let's approach your problem in a correct (or better?) way:

You have a sinusoidal voltage source: \$\mathrm{V_S=V_m\ \sin(\omega t)}\$.

And you have a capacitor connected to the source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9C7Oa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor's charge will be:

$$
\mathrm{
Q = C\ V_S = C\ V_m\ \sin(\omega t)
}
$$

And the current will be:

$$
\mathrm{
i(t)=\frac{dQ}{dt}
\\
\Rightarrow i(t)=\omega C \ V_m \ \cos(\omega t) = \omega C \ V_m \ \sin(\omega t + \pi / 2)
}
$$

We see that the current is still in \$\mathrm{i(t) = V(t) / R}\$ form. So the capacitive reactance is,

$$
\mathrm{
X_C=\frac{1}{\omega C}
}
$$

Please note that the last term \$\sin (\omega t + \pi / 2)\$ indicates that the current is a sine wave leading the voltage (\$\mathrm{V_s}\$ above) by 90 degrees.

---

Let's apply the same thing to an inductor with the same voltage source: \$\mathrm{V_S=V_m\ \sin(\omega t)}\$

We know that the inductor's voltage-current relationship:

$$
\mathrm{
v_L(t) = L \ \frac{di_L(t)}{dt}
\\
\Rightarrow i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \int{v_L(t)dt} = \frac{V_m}{L} \int{\sin(\omega t)dt}
\\
\Rightarrow i(t) = \frac{V_m}{\omega L} \ (-\cos(\omega t))
\\
\Rightarrow i(t) = \frac{V_m}{\omega L} \ \sin(\omega t - \pi / 2)
}
$$

As can be seen from above, the inductive reactance is \$\mathrm{X_L=\omega L}\$, and the current is a sinewave lagging behind the voltage (\$\mathrm{V_s}\$ above) by 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to write an answer because you were almost there! +1

Comment: How can I distinguish if the current lead or lag the voltage? For example, with inductance  reactance, I have $$i(t) = V_M/(Lw) cos(ωt)$$ but how can I choose $$\pm  
  \pi / 2$$

Comment: @Simone You don't choose. You see the lag/lead from the definition. I'm editing my answer. Check it in a few minutes. Please don't hesitate to ask anything you don't understand.

Comment: Current *leads* voltage with a capacitor. sin(wt - pi/2) shifts current +90 degrees.

Comment: @hacktastical `Current leads voltage with a capacitor.` yes and that is what I wrote in my answer. Could you please read it again and tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Nevermind... no issue.

Comment: @Rohat Can you explain to me why \$ \frac{d}{dt} = j \omega  \$ on the simpler proof of capacitive reactance?

Comment: @Simone \$d(e^{j\omega t})/dt=j\omega \ e^{j\omega t}\$. This is where the replacement comes from. Remember that this replacement can be done if the system is excited by a sinusoidal input (e.g. sinusoidal input voltage) because we can express sinusoidal functions with complex exponential functions (Remember Euler's equation).